# Combining multiple CSV files to a single xls file

Tags: excel, csv, vbscript, wsh

I have multiple CSV files say 5 of them, I want to consoildate all these CSV to a single excel workbook in separate sheets of that Combined excel file.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You did not specify a language or tech. so I understand you have no preferences. I had an article exactly on this using R: http://analystcave.com/r-staring-you-journey-with-r-and-machine-learning/

See an elegant solution in R below:

```
csv1 <- read.csv(file="testcsv1.csv", sep=";")
csv2 <- read.csv(file="testcsv2.csv", sep=";")
csvRes <- rbind(csv1,csv2)
write.table(csvRes, file="resCsv.csv", sep=";",row.names=FALSE)
```

Comment: Possibly in VB Script or CScript inside a batch file so that I can automate that.